# Storm java.lang.Runtime Exception: Returned channel was actually not established

Tags: apache-storm

This is time Storm again blocked me on an unknown problem. When I start storm, only part of worker are alive and then die while sometimes all workers are alive in a few seconds. So they just keep the loop from being alive and die.

I checked log file of workers, it keeps repeating one problem:
[ERROR] connection attempt *(from 1 to 25 actually) to Netty0Client-node1-1/10.19.1.1:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established.

(storm version- 0.9.5)

Comment: Where you able to find a solution? i am facing the same problem....

Comment: The reason to cause my problem is an error occurred in program execution. Therefore, every time when confronting this critical error, the work would continuously die and then be restarted.